# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Tags: python

Программа работает нормально без `tkinter` с `input` через строку, а когда пытаюсь ввести путь файла через граф, интерфейс выдаёт ошибку. Текст ошибки и код прикрепляю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grosscheff/Desktop/rea/gauss.py", line 29, in <module>
    xlsx = pd.read_excel(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\Grosscheff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Grosscheff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Grosscheff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 482, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\Grosscheff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1652, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "C:\Users\Grosscheff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1525, in inspect_excel_format
    with get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\Grosscheff\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 865, in get_handle
    handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

```
# импорт библиотек
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline
from scipy.stats import norm
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

filepath = ""

# Создание граф. интерфейса
    
window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x250')
window.title("REA.py")

def open_file():
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    print(filepath)
    if filepath != "":
        lbl = Label(window, text=filepath)  
        lbl.grid(column=1, row=0)

open_button = ttk.Button(text="Открыть файл", command=open_file)
open_button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW, padx=10)

xlsx = pd.read_excel(filepath)

 # Переименование столбцов для корректной работы программы
xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число избирателей, внесенных в список на момент окончания голосования':'ppl'}, inplace = True)
xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число избирателей, внесенных в список избирателей на момент окончания голосования':'ppl'}, inplace = True)
xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число избирателей, внесенных в список':'ppl'}, inplace = True)
xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число недействительных избирательных бюллетеней':'votes_false'}, inplace = True)
xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число недействительных бюллетеней':'votes_false'}, inplace = True)
xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число действительных бюллетеней':'votes_true'}, inplace = True)
xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число действительных избирательных бюллетеней':'votes_true'}, inplace = True)

# Создание датафрейма
df = pd.DataFrame(xlsx, columns = ['uik','ppl','votes_false','votes_true'])
data = df.to_numpy()

# Вычисление явки
turnout = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    turnout.append((data[i][3]+data[i][2])/data[i][1])
for i in range(len(data)):
    turnout[i] = (round(turnout[i]/0.01))

# Создание массивов со статистикой и процентами
stat=[]
percent = []
for i in range(101):
    stat.append(0)
    percent.append(i)

# Подведение статистики по явке
for i in range(len(turnout)):
    stat[turnout[i]]+=(data[i][3]+data[i][2])
        
# Создание гауссианы
density = []
expected_value = sum (turnout) / len (turnout)
standart_deviation = np.std (turnout)
coef = max (stat) / norm.pdf(expected_value, expected_value, standart_deviation)
for i in range (len (percent)):
    density.append(coef*norm.pdf(percent[i], expected_value, standart_deviation))

# Создание графика голосов
x = np.array (percent)
y = np.array (stat)

xnew = np.linspace (0, 100, 400) 

spl = make_interp_spline (x, y, k = 3)
y_smooth = spl (xnew)

# Создание графика голосов
x1 = np.array(percent)
y1 = np.array(density)

xnew1 = np.linspace (0, 100, 400)

spl1 = make_interp_spline (x1, y1, k = 3)
y_smooth1 = spl1 (xnew1)

# Вывод графиков
plt.plot (xnew, y_smooth)
plt.plot (xnew1, y_smooth1)
plt.title(filepath)
plt.xlabel("Turnout percent")
plt.ylabel("Votes")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашёл в использовании глобальных переменных

```
# импорт библиотек
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline
from scipy.stats import norm
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

# Создание граф. интерфейса
    
window = Tk()
window.geometry('400x250')
window.title("REA.py")

def open_file():
    global xlsx
    global filepath
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    lbl = Label(window, text=filepath)  
    lbl.grid(column=1, row=0)
    xlsx = pd.read_excel(filepath)

def load_file():
    xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число избирателей, внесенных в список на момент окончания голосования':'ppl'}, inplace = True)
    xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число избирателей, внесенных в список избирателей на момент окончания голосования':'ppl'}, inplace = True)
    xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число избирателей, внесенных в список':'ppl'}, inplace = True)
    xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число недействительных избирательных бюллетеней':'votes_false'}, inplace = True)
    xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число недействительных бюллетеней':'votes_false'}, inplace = True)
    xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число действительных бюллетеней':'votes_true'}, inplace = True)
    xlsx.rename(columns = {'Число действительных избирательных бюллетеней':'votes_true'}, inplace = True)

    # Создание датафрейма
    df = pd.DataFrame(xlsx, columns = ['uik','ppl','votes_false','votes_true'])
    data = df.to_numpy()

    # Вычисление явки
    turnout = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        turnout.append((data[i][3]+data[i][2])/data[i][1])
    for i in range(len(data)):
        turnout[i] = (round(turnout[i]/0.01))

    # Создание массивов со статистикой и процентами
    stat=[]
    percent = []
    for i in range(101):
        stat.append(0)
        percent.append(i)

    # Подведение статистики по явке
    for i in range(len(turnout)):
        stat[turnout[i]]+=(data[i][3]+data[i][2])
                    
    # Создание гауссианы
    density = []
    expected_value = sum (turnout) / len (turnout)
    standart_deviation = np.std (turnout)
    coef = max (stat) / norm.pdf(expected_value, expected_value, standart_deviation)
    for i in range (len (percent)):
        density.append(coef*norm.pdf(percent[i], expected_value, standart_deviation))

    # Создание графика голосов
    x = np.array (percent)
    y = np.array (stat)

    xnew = np.linspace (0, 100, 400) 

    spl = make_interp_spline (x, y, k = 3)
    y_smooth = spl (xnew)

    # Создание графика голосов
    x1 = np.array(percent)
    y1 = np.array(density)

    xnew1 = np.linspace (0, 100, 400)

    spl1 = make_interp_spline (x1, y1, k = 3)
    y_smooth1 = spl1 (xnew1)

    # Вывод графиков
    plt.plot (xnew, y_smooth)
    plt.plot (xnew1, y_smooth1)
    plt.title(filepath)
    plt.xlabel("Turnout percent")
    plt.ylabel("Votes")
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


open_button = ttk.Button(text="Выбрать файл", command=open_file)
open_button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW, padx=10)
load_button = ttk.Button(text="Запустить программу", command=load_file)
load_button.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=NSEW, padx=10)
window.mainloop()
```